# Hide And show html tab with a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is my code ..i code a php page where i want, if we select scholarship status `yes` then some options show below like bank name , branch etc and if we select scholarship status `no` , then not show any option.

```
 <div class="controls">
      <select id="" name="Scholarship info">
          <option value="">select</option>
          <option value="yes">yes</option>
          <option value="no">no</option>
      </select>
 </div>
```

and if we select `yes` then show that options otherwise if we select no ..not show below options....

```
 <div class="controls">
        <select id="" name="Bank name">
             <option value="">select</option>
             <option value="state bank">State bank</option>
             <option value="Canera Bank">Canera bank</option>
        </select>
 </div>  
 <div class="controls">
        <select id="" name="Branch name">
             <option value="">select</option>
             <option value="amethi">amethi</option>
             <option value="lucknow">lucknow</option>
        </select>
 </div>  
 <div class="controls">
        <select id="" name="account number">
           <input type="text" class="span6 typeahead" name="acoountnumber" placeholder="account number" value="<?php echo
set_value('accountnumber'); ?>" />

</div>
```

Comment: Make the div `visibility: hidden` and then add a Javascript method for the `option` to make the div visible if that option is selected.

Answer (score 0):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Hd6WC/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("select[name='Bank name']").hide();
    $("select[name='Branch name']").hide();
    $("select[name='account number']").hide();
    $("input[name='acoountnumber']").hide();


});


$("select[name='Scholarship info']").change(function() {


    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    if(selectedVal == 'yes') {

        $("select[name='Bank name']").show();
        $("select[name='Branch name']").show();
        $("select[name='account number']").show();
        $("input[name='acoountnumber']").show();
    } else {

         $("select[name='Bank name']").hide();
        $("select[name='Branch name']").hide();
        $("select[name='account number']").hide();
        $("input[name='acoountnumber']").hide();

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add an extra class, `withScholarship` to the `div`s you want to show and hide, it is gets even easier. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yyS7b/)

```
<div class="controls">
  <select id="" name="Scholarship info">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="yes">yes</option>
    <option value="no">no</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="controls withScholarship">
  <select id="" name="Bank name">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="state bank">State bank</option>
    <option value="Canera Bank">Canera bank</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="controls withScholarship">
  <select id="" name="Branch name">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="amethi">amethi</option>
    <option value="lucknow">lucknow</option>
  </select>
</div>  
<div class="controls withScholarship">
    <input type="text" class="span6 typeahead" name="acoountnumber" placeholder="account number" value="121"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".withScholarship").hide();
  $("select[name='Scholarship info']").change(function() {
    var flag = $(this).val() == "yes";
    $(".withScholarship").toggle(flag);
  })
</script>
```

Comment: You can also put the controls you want to hide in one container div with a class of 'withScholarship' and the same code will work. `<div class="withScholarship"><div class="controls">...</div>...</div>`

Comment: Very very thanks..sir it very nice method with example.

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer you end up using and upvote the answers that helped you.